# How to fix the error "argument of type HTML element | null is not assignable to parameter of type 'TargetElement' using react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

i have a switch element in dom like so

```
<div>
    <label for="source"/>
    <label value="false" class="StyledSwitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="source" id="source">
        <i class="ball-container"></i>
        <span class="label" data-enabled="On" data-disabled="Off"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

now i get the input element with id "source" using react-testing-library

```
const switch = document.getElementById('source')
if (switch) {
    userEvent.click(switch);
}
```

the above snippet works. but this switch is always present so i dont want to check for switch in if statement. when i remove if statement like below,

```
const switch = document.getElementById('source')
userEvent.click(switch);
```

i get error like below,

```
"argument of type HTML element | null is not assignable to parameter of type 'TargetElement'
```

could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: Use RTL queries to access DOM elements rather than using `document.getElementById`.